# antlr4 java7 grammar to parse java 8 files

Tags: antlr4

Is there any way that I can use antlr4 java 7 grammar to parse java8 files without adding much changes to the java.g4 grammar file. As far as I understand the syntactical changes from java7 to java8 are the lambda expression syntax and the double column operator. I was able to incorporate the lambda expression but to include the double column operator in my current grammar file seems a bit complex.

Comment: Have you tried the Java 8 grammar from the ANTLR repo: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4 ?

Comment: Yes. But I can't simply move to java 8 from java 7. I have written a set of APIs  which depends on the rule names of java 7 grammar. What I have been looking is to incorporate the java 8 newly introduced syntax elements in my existing java 7 grammar. Would that be too difficult. I tried incorporating the lambda constructs which worked fine. but the new double column operator is a little complex to include in the existing grammar.